# Create column with true/false for previous month

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a column with dates in the following format:
yyyy/m/d

How can I create a calculated column that has as values true for every entry that is on the previous month and false for the rest? I've tried as below, but i don't get the correct output.

```
IF(Date = DATE_SUB(DATE_TRUNC(Date, MONTH), INTERVAL 1 MONTH), TRUE, FALSE) AS PreviousMonth
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

If your date column is of STRING data type with format yyyy/m/d (as it is stated in original question) - you can use below

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *, 
  DATE_TRUNC(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH), MONTH) = 
  DATE_TRUNC(PARSE_DATE('%Y/%m/%d', date), MONTH) AS PreviousMonth 
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

If your data column is of DATE data type - you should use below

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *, 
  DATE_TRUNC(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH), MONTH) = 
  DATE_TRUNC(date, MONTH) AS PreviousMonth 
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

Comment: Hi MIkhali, My date is in Date data type. Do i need to use PARSE_DATE here.I have modified like this. It shows an error. 
DATE_TRUNC(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH), MONTH) =  DATE_TRUNC(Date), MONTH) AS PreviousMonth

Comment: you mentioned it is in `yyyy/m/d` format so I thought it is a `string`. But if it is a `date` you just replace `PARSE_DATE('%Y/%m/%d', date)` with `date` . See update in my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can try this alternative option:

```
WITH querytable AS(
  SELECT '2020/06/29' AS input_date
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '2020/07/29' AS input_date
  UNION ALL
  SELECT '2020/08/30' AS input_date )
SELECT
  PrevMonth,
  CurrMonth,
  IF(PrevMonth = CurrMonth, TRUE, FALSE) true_false
FROM (
  SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM PARSE_DATE('%Y/%m/%d', input_date)) AS PrevMonth,
         EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) AS CurrMonth
  FROM
    querytable)
```